# Best Practice of redirecting in Spring Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Here I have to controller methods for example,

(Case 1) One way is

```
@Controller
@requestMapping("main")
Class ControllerClass{

    @RequestMapping("first", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String post(Model model){
       //processing  
       return "redirect:second";
    }

    @RequestMapping("second", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String post(Model model){
       //processing  
       return "myview";
    }
}
```

And (Case 2) another way is

```
@Controller
@requestMapping("main")
Class ControllerClass{

    @RequestMapping("first", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String post(Model model){
       //processing  
       return "redirect:/main/second";
    }

    @RequestMapping("second", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String post(Model model){
       //processing  
       return "myview";
    }
}
```

Both ways work correctly, but I want to know which one is better to avoid future problems like one I faced recently:

When I forwarded the request to **/main/first** from another controller, I got a 404 error in code which is using Case 1.

Comment: Does the first case really work? There is no mapping matching `second`, there is only one matching `main/second`, am I wrong?

Comment: @sp00m Yes it is perfectly working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per Spring Documentation:

The redirect: prefix

While the use of RedirectView works fine, if the controller itself creates the RedirectView, there is no avoiding the fact that the controller is aware that a redirection is happening. This is really suboptimal and couples things too tightly. The controller should not really care about how the response gets handled. In general it should operate only in terms of view names that have been injected into it.

The special redirect: prefix allows you to accomplish this. If a view name is returned that has the prefix redirect:, the UrlBasedViewResolver (and all subclasses) will recognize this as a special indication that a redirect is needed. The rest of the view name will be treated as the redirect URL.

The net effect is the same as if the controller had returned a RedirectView, but now the controller itself can simply operate in terms of logical view names. A logical view name such as redirect:/myapp/some/resource will redirect relative to the current Servlet context, while a name such as redirect:http://myhost.com/some/arbitrary/path will redirect to an absolute URL.

**Most Real time enterprise project prefers to use case 2 in all controllers they use,so that the inter calling  between different controller is fine.**